# Relating content in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, related-content, drupal-entities

Need a drupal help.

I have two content types, works and clients.

When I'm adding a new work I'd like to include the client which the work was for, so I can display the client´s logo on the work detail page.

Each work only has one client and each client can be in many works.

I don't have a clue where to start.

Comment: What version of Drupal? https://www.drupal.org/project/references

Comment: Use either node reference or entity reference